# Connect to a remote Database at home from work

Tags: windows-10

I have a laptop running Windows 10 in my home, with Oracle DB installed.

This laptop is connected to the Internet.

I need to access the database on that laptop from anywhere.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Have you configured the database to allow remote connections.  It is normal for a database, by default for security reasons, to only accept internal network connections ( intranet ).

Comment: I want to be able to access it from work for ex.

Comment: Question is to put the PC online

Comment: I know what you want to do.  I was simply asking if you had configured to the database service to allow remote connections.

Comment: Why don't you create a VPN to your home network where you can keep your database only open to your LAN IPs and you'll be able to access it securely from anywhere... OpenVPN, SoftEther etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start saying that opening up a database for **everyone** is not a good idea from the security point of view, even if it's a robust data base manager as Oracle. It's always better opening access to the IPs or IP ranges that you'll be using, and filter any other access.

That said, in order to forward traffic to your Oracle database, you'll first need to know 2 things about your Windows machine:

- The private IP address of your machine (which can be easily discovered running the `ipconfig` command)
- The port where the Oracle DB listens (usually with `netstat -a`)

Having that, you need to open up your router configuration and add a rule in your Port Forwarding section. You need to add a rule so the port where the Oracle DB listens should be forwarded to the private IP address of your Windows box and the port you discovered.

You should then configure your Windows firewall to allow that post being reached from the outside as well.

That should be enough to open the access from the outside. If it doesn't work, also keep in mind that the antivirus system might be blocking external access to your apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to your oracle db using easy connect.

If you want to connect using SQLPLUS to SCOTT using the password TIGER on the database DEV01 (which is listening on the default port). The host name is BIGSERVER. The syntax would be:

`sqlplus scott/tiger@BIGSERVER/DEV01`

If the port was 1616 instead of 1521, I would use

`sqlplus scott/tiger@BIGSERVER:1616/DEV01`

You can also connect to a URL using the Easy Connect Syntax. If you want to connect using this syntax, use syntax such as:

`sqlplus scott/tiger@//BIGSERVER/DEV01"`

[link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_news/2006_04_04_connect_using_easy_connect.htm)

Comment: This is not a correct answer. The OP wasnts to connect his Oracle DB from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I double nKn. However, as he has stated this is a major security threat to your home broadband.

In short -

1. Currently your Oracle database listener service is running on your_laptop_ip_address:port
2. It is accessible to all devices on your home network ONLY.
3. Configuring port forwarding to forward your_laptop_ip_address:port to your_router_static_ip_address:port will allow the internet to access it (I suggest setting up some authentication on the router).
4. Router port forwarding configuration is described here: http://ee.co.uk/help/phones-and-device/home-broadband/bright-box-wireless-router/bright-box-advanced-user-guides/bright-box-router-set-up-port-forwarding and if you have a flair for basic networking you can traslate this for your own router.